# Add an event listener to a particular part of a 3D Object in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am having a human body object and what I want is that my code should open a popup whenever I click on any of the specified body parts such as eyes, nose, arms, etc. The object is a single compiled .obj file and I'm unable to figure out as to how should I attach an event listener to the multiple body parts. Any kind of help is much appreciated!

PS: - I am also using orbit controls to handle the zoom and rotation of object.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, it's necessary to design your model in a way such that individual components like arms, eyes etc. are independent 3D objects grouped together to build a more complex asset. This is something you have to ensure during the design phase with a tool like Blender.

In the next step export to glTF instead of OBJ, load the model with `THREE.GLTFLoader` into your app and then perform a recursive raycasting with the entire asset via:

```js
raycaster.intersectObject( gltf.scene, true, intersects );
```

By executing this code in a `pointermove` or `pointerdown` event listener you can find out whether the user interacts with the model or not.

Notice that `three.js` has no system to directly assign event listeners to 3D objects. You have to use a different solution like raycasting for this.